# How can I convert month to quarter?

Tags: python, date

I would like to convert from month to quarter with just using month number. For example: (11 - 4), (5 - 2) (Month - Quarter).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This seems to been a rather simple task. What are the problems you are facing?

Comment: Let me give you a hint: `math.ceil(....)`. Fill in the dots yourself

Comment: `(month - 1) // 3 + 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
int(MONTH//3.1)+1

for i in range(1,13) :
    print('month : ',i,'quarter :',int(i//3.1)+1)
```

will print:

```
month :  1 quarter : 1
month :  2 quarter : 1
month :  3 quarter : 1
month :  4 quarter : 2
month :  5 quarter : 2
month :  6 quarter : 2
month :  7 quarter : 3
month :  8 quarter : 3
month :  9 quarter : 3
month :  10 quarter : 4
month :  11 quarter : 4
month :  12 quarter : 4
```